# Can't find AVD Manager in Mac OS

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, sdk, android-virtual-device

I'm running Eclipse Juno and have installed the SDK manager for Android for the Mac OS.  Things seemed to be going fine, could import old projects as new Android app.

The problem is I can't find the AVD manager.  I went to Windows-> and I do not see options for SDK manager or AVD manager.

I went to run a project and it asked me to create a device using the AVD manager, so it's installed, I used it.  Is my set up incorrect?  Does the latest version of Eclipse just not have it?

Comment: Are you sure you have installed the plugin to Eclipse properly? I'm running Eclipse version: 4.2.1 on OSX and I have SDK and AVD manager under Window.

Comment: No, I'm not sure.  Where would I find the information about how to install the plugin?

Comment: Go through http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html or specifically http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html for the ADT plugin.

Comment: It says all the plugins are installed when I went to install the plugins.

Answer (score -1):

I was using the wrong version of Eclipse.  You need to install Eclipse per usual, download the Android SDK, then use the one in the version in the adt-bundle-mac directory. That one is the one with the version of Eclipse with the Android plugins. Just answered this for anyone else who is having this problem.